# How to remove the default HTTP headers added in Paw?

Tags: http-headers, paw-app

When creating a simple HTTP `HEAD` request in Paw, e.g. to `http://example.com` then Paw automatically injects the `Connection` and `User-Agent` HTTP headers. Is there a way to remove those headers completely?

I know that I can replace the values of these headers by specifying the header manually, but that does not drop the headers from the request, i.e. the request looks like:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: Paw/3.0.15 (Macintosh; OS X/10.11.6) GCDHTTPRequest
```

But I want it to look like:

```
HEAD / HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it isn't possible to completely remove these headers in Paw (as of version 3.1.8). Though, you can set them to an empty value by overriding the headers yourself:

[image]

Comment: in my specific case, I fell back to a low level approach, since I figured that it is not possible with Paw. It seems like it is not even possible to drop the headers completely using the URLSession API directly. Removing values for headers was not what I was looking for, but might be valuable feedback for other users having a similar problem.